# jQuery dropdown menu, submenus open internally instead of to the side

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover

I have created a jQuery menu with dropdowns, but when I hover over subMenu items, I want them to open to the left. The only results I can, however, or either that they open down in the current submenu, or if I add a position: absolute or position: relative and give them a margin-left or left: they are not visible.

This is a link to a '[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sdSn/2/)' with it opening vertically.

My CSS:

```
            .mainLinks {
            width: 150px;

            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;

            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;

            background-color: #000000;
        }

        .mainLinks a {
            padding: 10px 0;
            display: block;

            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .mainLinks a:hover {
            background: #0000bb
        }

        .sub {
            position: relative;
        }

        .sub li a {
            display: block;
            float: none;
        }

        .subSub {
            position: relative;
        }

        .subSub li a {
            display: block;
            float: none;
        }
```

This is my jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.sub').hide();
            $('.subSub').hide();

            $('#menu li').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).children('.sub').stop().slideToggle(350);
                },

                function() {
                    $(this).children('.sub').stop().delay(100).slideToggle(350);
                }
            );

            $('.sub li').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).children('.subSub').stop().slideToggle(150);
                },

                function() {
                    $(this).children('.subSub').stop().delay(100).slideToggle(150);
                }
            );
        });
```

And this is the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="menu">

            <ul id="menuBar">

                <li class="mainLinks"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                <li class="mainLinks"><a href="#">Products</a>

                    <ul id="sub00" class="sub">

                        <li><a href="#">Motherboards</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Cooling Options</a>

                            <ul id="sub01" class="subSub">

                                <li><a href="#">Fans</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#">Liquid Cooling</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#">Thermal Paste</a></li>      

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Graphics Cards</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>

                            <ul id="sub02" class="subSub">

                                <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#">Webcams</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#">Headphones</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li class="mainLinks"><a href="#">Support</a></li>

                <li class="mainLinks"><a href="#">Community</a>

                    <ul id="sub03" class="sub">

                        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Messaging</a></li>      

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li class="mainLinks"><a href="#">Partners</a></li>     

            </ul>

            </div>

    </div>
```

I just need the sub submenus to open to the right. They use the class .subSub. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this **[Fiddle](http://goo.gl/R0cegM)**

```
ul.sub li {
position: relative;
}
.subSub {
position: absolute;
    background: black;
    left: 110px;
    top : 10px;
}
```